# Convincing R to exclude single level factors when using lm() in a for loop in some subsets (but not all)

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am working on a large dataset with 19 subcohorts for which I want to run a lineair regression model to estimate BMI.

One of the covariates I am using is sex, but some subcohorts consist only of men, which causes problems in my loop. 
If I try to run a linear regression model, I get the following error:

tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels

I have found a solution for this problem, by running seperate loops for subcohorts with men and subcohorts with men and women by the following (simplified) code:

```
men <- c(1,6,15) # Cohort nrs that only contain men
menandwomen <- c(2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,16,17,18,19)

trenddpmodelm <-list()
for(i in men) {
trenddpmodelm[[i]] <- lm(BMI ~ age +  sex,                                               
data=subcohort[subcohort$centre_a==i, ],)
}

trenddpmodelmw <-list()
for(i in menandwomen) {
trenddpmodelmw[[i]] <- lm(BMI ~ age + sex,  
data=subcohort[subcohort$centre_a==i, ],)
}

trenddpmodel <- c(list(trenddpmodelm[[1]]), list(trenddpmodelmw[[2]]),     list(trenddpmodelmw[[3]]), list(trenddpmodelmw[[4]]), list(trenddpmodelmw[[5]]), list(trenddpmodelm[[6]]), list(trenddpmodelmw[[7]]), list(trenddpmodelmw[[8]]), list(trenddpmodelmw[[9]]), list(trenddpmodelmw[[10]]), list(trenddpmodelmw[[11]]), list(trenddpmodelmw[[12]]), list(trenddpmodelmw[[13]]), list(trenddpmodelmw[[14]]), list(trenddpmodelm[[15]]), list(trenddpmodelmw[[16]]), list(trenddpmodelmw[[17]]), list(trenddpmodelmw[[18]]), list(trenddpmodelmw[[19]]))
```

After this step, I extract relevant information from the summaries and put this in a df to export to excel. 
My problem is that I will be running quite a lot of analyses, which will result in pages and pages of code.

My question is therefore: **Is there a setting in R that I could use that allows non varying factors to be dropped from my lineair regression model in subcohorts where this is applicable?** (similar to what happens in coxph; R gives a warning that the factor does not always vary, but the loop does run)

It is not like I cannot continue working without a solution, but I have been trying to find an answer to this question for days without succes and I think it must be possible somehow. Any advice is much appreciated :)

Comment: Yeah the loop is not the problem. The problem is that the factor sex does not vary in all of the cohorts in the loop, which leads to an error. I have posted my solution to that problem here, but I just think that there should be a more efficient solution than mine that does not require so much code

Comment: Is there a particular reason to model separately for each cohort and not use one model (e.g., a linear mixed effects model) for all cohorts?

Comment: Hi Roland. There is a reason for that actually. I am performing a Mendelian Randomization study in which you estimate the relationship between a gene and an exposure, the relationship between a gene and your outcome of interest and from that you can deduct your exposure-outcome relationship. I am not that familiar with mixed effects models, but I need point estimates per cohort and cannot use random effects because it might introduce bias.. Will look into it again though, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend building your formula dynamically within the loop.

```
DF <- list(Cohort1 = data.frame(bmi = rnorm(25, 24, 1),
                                age = rnorm(25, 50, 3),
                                sex = sample(c("F", "M"), 25, replace = TRUE)),
           Cohort2 = data.frame(bmi = rnorm(15, 24, 1),
                                age = rnorm(15, 55, 4),
                                sex = rep("M", 15)))

candidate_vars <- c("age", "sex")

Models <- vector("list", length(DF))
for (i in seq_along(DF)){

  # Determine if the variables are either numeric, or factor with more than 1 level
  indep <- vapply(X = DF[[i]][candidate_vars],
                  FUN = function(x){
                    if (is.numeric(x)) return(TRUE)
                    else return(nlevels(x) > 1)
                  },
                  FUN.VALUE = logical(1))
  # Write the formula
  form <- paste("bmi ~ ", paste(candidate_vars[indep], collapse = " + "))

  # Create the model
  Models[[i]] <- lm(as.formula(form), data = DF[[i]])
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I cannot get the code to work yet because I am currently using DF[DF$var==i] rather than DF[[i]] in my script, but I think I can find a way around that. Very informative example!