# Automatically exclude single-level factor variables from regression

Tags: r, regression, factors

I have a custom function which, among other things, creates a regression formula based on specified string inputs and runs a regression (`brm`, but should work similarly for basic `lm`):

```
model_predict <- function(.data, dep_var, model ...) {
    form <- as.formula(str_glue("{dep_var} ~ {model}"))
    form_vars <- all.vars(form)

    ... # some other stuff

    fit <- brm(form, .data, ...)

    ... # some other stuff
}
```

I use this to fit a large number of pre-specified models as part of a larger workflow.

Sometimes, some of the variables in `model` are factor variables, and sometimes those factors have only one level in the data. This results in the `contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels` error when trying to fit the model.

Because of the larger workflow and because it's not always clear *a priori* if the data and model for any given iteration is going to encounter this problem, I'd rather not manually remove the factor vars from the model specified when those vars only have one level in the relevant data subset.

**Is there is some setting on `lm` or `brm` that can be used to tell the model fitting process itself to ignore single-level factor vars?** that would be the easiest solution, but I'm not sure it exists.

Alternatively, I'd like an automated solution that identifies when the single factor level situation arises, and drops the relevant vars from the formula when it does (maybe giving a warning message too), for instance:

```
# main formula
form
> outcome ~ predictor_1 + predictor_2 * interactor

# Desired outputs...
# if predictor_1 has only one level in data
> outcome ~ predictor_2 * interactor

# if predictor_2 has only one level in data
> outcome ~ predictor_1

# if interactor has only one level in data
> outcome ~ predictor_1 + predictor_2
```

I've tried `tryCatch` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49865845/how-to-get-regression-output-in-r-ignoring-one-factor-level-in-data) but while that suppresses the `contrasts...` error, it returns `NULL` instead of a fitted model ignoring the offending vars, which is what I need.

Additionally, sometimes those variables are in the formula with `+` and sometimes with `*` as interaction effects, which makes [dynamically building the formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39870739/convincing-r-to-exclude-single-level-factors-when-using-lm-in-a-for-loop-in-so) difficult.

Comment: Are the model variables always factors, or only occasionally?

Comment: Only some of the model variables are factors.

Comment: Applying a zero-variance filter to your variables before fitting should solve this. The `recipes` package's `step_zv()` function would work.

Comment: @Seth I haven't used `tidymodels` but looking at the documentation `step_zv()` sounds promising. Can it work without switching to a full `tidymodels` workflow though? could you give an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```r
# For pipe operator
library(magrittr)

# Define function for updating the model
update_formula <- function(data, dep_var, model) {
  # Extract model variables
  model_vars <- stringr::str_split_1(model, '\\+|\\*|:') %>% 
    stringr::str_trim()
  
  model_terms <- stringr::str_split_1(model, '\\+') %>% 
    stringr::str_trim()
  
  # Get the number of levels for all factor variables
  lev_leng <- .data %>% 
    dplyr::select(where(is.factor) & any_of(model_vars)) %>% 
    purrr::map_int(
      ~ length(levels(droplevels(.x)))
    )
  
  # Check if length is one
  invalid <- names(which(lev_leng == 1))
  
  # If any is invalid, it will have length > 0
  if (length(invalid) != 0) {
    for (i in invalid) {
      if (any(stringr::str_detect(model_terms, paste0('\\*[:space:]?', i)))) {
        # Remove interactor from formula
        model_terms <- stringr::str_remove(
          model_terms,
          paste0('[\\*,:]?[:space:]?',i,'[:space:]?[\\*,:]?')
        )
      } else{
        # Remove entire term from formula
        model_terms <- model_terms[stringr::str_detect(model_terms, i, T)]
      }
    }
    model <- stringr::str_flatten(model_terms, '+')
  }
  # Define the new formula
  as.formula(glue::glue('{dep_var} ~ {model}'))
}


# Dep var defition
dep_var <- 'y'
# Model example
model <- "predictor_1 + predictor_2 * interactor"

# Example predictor_1
.data <- tibble::tibble(
  y = runif(10),
  predictor_1 = factor(1),
  predictor_2 = factor(letters[1:10]),
  interactor  = factor(letters[1:10])
)

# Update model
form <- update_formula(.data, dep_var, model)
form
#> y ~ predictor_2 * interactor
#> <environment: 0x0000015b95006a58>

# Fit the model
fit <- lm(form, .data)

# Example predictor_2
.data <- tibble::tibble(
  y = runif(10),
  predictor_1 = runif(10),
  predictor_2 = factor(letters[rep(1, 10)]),
  interactor  = factor(letters[1:10])
)

form <- update_formula(.data, dep_var, model)
form
#> y ~ predictor_1
#> <environment: 0x0000015b95cdd218>

# Example interactor
.data <- tibble::tibble(
  y = runif(10),
  predictor_1 = runif(10),
  predictor_2 = factor(letters[1:10]),
  interactor  = factor(letters[rep(1, 10)])
)

form <- update_formula(.data, dep_var, model)
form
#> y ~ predictor_1 + predictor_2
#> <environment: 0x0000015b96072878>

# Example predictor_1 & interactor
.data <- tibble::tibble(
  y = runif(10),
  predictor_1 = factor(10),
  predictor_2 = factor(letters[1:10]),
  interactor  = factor(letters[rep(1, 10)])
)

form <- update_formula(.data, dep_var, model)
form
#> y ~ predictor_2
#> <environment: 0x0000015b9669d448>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks @Baraliuh, this looks pretty good. Is there some way to eliminate reliance on `if (i == 'interactor')` though? as there will be many potential variables being used as interactors. My R regex/stringr skills are nonexistent but maybe based on the fact that interactors will always be preceded by `*` rather than `+`?

Comment: Yeah! We can fix that. Are they always called 'interactor<something>' or is it fixed that other variables are always called 'predictor_[0-9]'? If so, the if-clause can just be inverted.

Comment: I think that as long as you have some formal definition of what an interactor is (e.g., not called `predictor_[0-9]`) then it should be fine. I updated the answer assuming predictors are always named `predictor_<something>'. Let me know if it works or what doesn't.

Comment: Yeah it would also be possible to do `any(str_detect(model_terms, paste0('\\*', i)))` in the if-clause. If true remove only `\\*, i` else drop term completely.

Comment: Variable names are widely differing (I used `predictor` and `interactor` as placeholders) but by definition, given formula syntax, interactors will always be preceded by `*`

Comment: @TYLim I think that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

An approach to reformulate the formula based on valid columns (assuming the response variable stays the same):

- example data:

```
d <- data.frame(Y = rnorm(2),
                x1 = gl(1, 1),
                x2 = gl(1, 2),
                x3 = LETTERS[1:2],
                x4 = rnorm(2)
                )
```

- helper function to detect unwanted variables in dataframe `d`

```
get_vars_to_omit <- \(d){
  names(d) |>
    sapply(FUN = \(name){xs <- d[[name]]
      is.numeric(xs) | (length(levels(as.factor(xs))) > 1)
    }) |>
    Filter(f = \(xs) !xs) |>  names()
}
```

```
> get_vars_to_omit(d)
[1] "x1" "x2"
```

- helper function to update an existing model formula by removing terms containing unwanted variables:

```
update_formula <- function(old_formula, vars_to_omit){
  var_names <- all.vars(old_formula)
  old_terms <- terms(old_formula)
  terms_to_drop <- attr(old_terms, 'term.labels') |>
    grep(pattern = paste(vars_to_omit, collapse = '|'))
  new_terms <- drop.terms(old_terms, terms_to_drop)
  attr(new_terms, 'term.labels') |> 
    reformulate(response = var_names[1])
}
```

- example formula containing unwanted variables:

```
old_formula <- formula(Y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4)
```

- update formula:

```
new_formula <- update_formula(old_formula, get_vars_to_omit(d))
```

```
## terms with unwanted variables have been removed:
## > new_formula
Y ~ x3 + x4
```

- result:

```
## > lm(new_formula, data = d)

Call:
lm(formula = new_formula, data = d)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)          x3B           x4  
      0.901       -1.222           NA
```

(edit ends here)

---

Could you add some a knock-out step at the start? Like:

```
d |> select_if(~ is.numeric(.x) | (length(levels(as.factor(.x))) > 1))
```

Above is a "tidy" variant which can also expressed with `lapply` or `Map` of base R. For a more automated feature selection, {[caret](https://topepo.github.io/caret/index.html)} or {[tidymodels](https://www.tidymodels.org/)} might be worth a try.

Comment: But if the knock-out step identifies and removes a single-level factor variable from the data that's still included in the model formula, won't it throw an error because now the model includes a variable not in the data?

Comment: I'd add a `droplevels` into your second condition as it is possible for a factor to have multiple levels but only one unique value

Comment: I rewrote the answer including a solution for dynamic re-formulation avoiding unwanted variables.